# Adding one day to last day of the month

Tags: c#, datetime

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;  

var lastDayOfMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
day = dt.Day;
if (day != lastDayOfMonth)
{
    if (dt.Hour >= 14)
    {
        day = day + 1;
    }
    else if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        day = day + 1;
}
else
{
    //  
}
```

Now I want to add one day to the last day of the month. How can i do it?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: c#..sorry for not mentioning

Comment: So do you want to get the first day of next month?

Comment: if you want to add one day to the last day of the month,
isn't this enough -> day = day + 1;

If not, can you rephrase your question?

Comment: yeah.if i add one day to the last day of the month,it should be the first day of next month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i did this by removing the if condition for lastDayOfMonth and using AddDays property.

```
                if (dt.Hour >= 14)
                {
                    dt.AddDays(1);
                }
                else if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                    dt.AddDays(1);
                }
                day = dt.Day;
```

thankyou everyone for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
newDate = date.AddDays(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just need [`DateTime.AddDays` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of days to the
>   value of this instance.

But [`DateTime.Day`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property returns `int`. If you just want to add it `1`, you are in a right way.

```
day = day + 1;
```

But this doesn't affect `dt` of course.

Ok, let's look at your exact problem now..

Adding `1` month and then extracting `1` day is the one of the best way to find out the last day of the current month.

For example;

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
var FirstDayOfNextMonth = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1).AddMonths(1);
var LastDayOfCurrentMonth = FirstDayOfNextMonth.AddDays(-1);
Console.WriteLine(LastDayOfCurrentMonth);
```

Output will be;

```
2/28/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/KnB03z)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime firstDayOfThisMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
DateTime firstDayOfNextMonth = firstDayOfThisMonth.AddMonths(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the first day of next month you can use

`Datetime FirstDayofNxtMnth =DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,1);`

To find the Last day of this month you can use

`Datetime FirstDayofNxtMnth =DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,1);`

`Datetime LastDayofThisMnth =DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,1).addDay(-1);`